# How do questions in meta affect bans in main (or vice-versa)?

Tags: discussion, reputation

I have a question ban on the main site saying:

> Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more.

So I go to help center and it tells me:

> How can I get out of a question ban?
>
> The ban will be lifted automatically by the system when it determines that your positive contributions outweigh those questions which were poorly received.

Does asking good questions in meta help lift the ban? Also, how much good do you have to do? Is it measured in reputation or the number of people reached?

---

> Title revised by a moderator to cover both cases, where such a ban exists on either Meta or Main, and this is referenced in the bold-text on the accepted answer from the moderator.

Comment: Remember, well received answers are positive contributions too.

Comment: Here is a meta.se post about this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th it is a bit long for me to quote it as an answer :)

Comment: Sorry, it didn't help, I mean it answer neither of my quetions. :(

Comment: To answer your first question, NO, rep and votes are tracked independently, so what you do one should no affect the other (apart from in the case of moderator intervention, of course). "Is it measured in reputation or the number of people reached?" AFAIK it is a metric of good post vs bad posts rather than individual vote count. I do not know the exact metrics. "I have a question ban, why?" That affects the meaning of your post, I looked at your profile and you do not have any bad posts (unless you removed them? don't do that, flag for closing), why are you banned?

Comment: I am banned for asking too many bad questions. I did delete many though, so I wouldn't lose more rep.

Comment: That is what got you banned, don't delete them, edit them and drop in chat to ask for users to revote. This makes it tricky to get unbanned as you can no longer improve the posts. Do some editing, flagging etc and if you can some answers, this should contribute towards getting you unblocked, meta will not help.

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't that go against the rules?

Comment: Why? You mean the asking in chat bit? Only if you are begging for votes or promoting yourself, a simple request for review is perfectly fine. Just scroll up a bit in chat and you will see me asked for voting to be revised after a user made an edit.

Comment: Oh, I see. It is not blindly voting.

Comment: Yes, don't ask them to vote, ask them to revise existing votes, I don't see a reson anyone would take issue with that :)

Comment: @UbuntuUser If you have questions you deleted that you think you might be able to make better, you may want to start there. You can edit them even while they're still deleted, then undelete them. You cannot undelete questions that were deleted by a moderator, but if you [have fixed them](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask) then you could ask for them to be restored. Are there particular questions of yours that you've deleted yourself that you'd be interested in input on how possibly to improve? (As a 10k user I can view deleted posts, but I can't search for them.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Meta contributions have *absolutely no effect* on system-instituted question or answer bans on the main site.**

**The same applies for the inverse, as well - contributions on the main site have *absolutely no effect* on system-institutted question or answer bans on the Meta site.**

Your question-ban is in place on the *main site* because a substantial portion of your asked questions were flagged as content that is poor, and/or were closed as offtopic or duplicates of other items, and/or were deleted.  When a substantial portion of your questions are flagged and/or deleted by community voting and review queues, the system automatically institutes that block.

To get rid of the question-ban, you have to contribute positively to the main site in other methods, such as posting good answers and other positive activity.  Once the system determines that you have enough positive contributions to outweigh the evils which led to the question ban being instituted, the system will automatically remove that block and you can then ask questions again.  (This cannot be influenced by moderators or staff)

The system-instituted question and answer blocks operate indepdently of each other on a given main site and its corresponding Meta site.  They have no impact on each other.

(Rule violation suspensions, on the other hand, affect both the main and Meta site, so if you get suspended by a moderator or a community manager for rule violations, or the system automatically as a result of some other thing behind the scenes, you're banned on both sites, and not just for posting questions and answers, but from doing anything except browsing site content and replying to moderator direct messages sent to you - in effect, read only mode.)

---

As for your other two questions:

> Also, how much good do you have to do?
>   Is it measured in reputation or the number of people reached?

This information is not known to the public.  It is an internal, secret, undisclosed algorithm that only the StackExchange software devs truly understand.  We cannot measure the exact extent of what you have to do to resolve such a ban, as it can't be quantified without SE releasing that information (which they won't do).